# Spring integration-Service activator getting called twice

Tags: spring-integration

Hi this is my spring integration configuration..When i hit my service using mozilla fire fox rest console two times its getting called.For example if i hit some service in service-activator (CA request activator),On certaion un predicatable scenarios it s getting called twice.I dont know whetther it is mozilla issue or configuration issue.I tried using new window but this problem persists.In first case my service activator returning xml response properly  but immediately it s getting called again.Only on rare scenarios its calling twice.

```
    <int:channel id="accountRequest" />
    <int:channel id="accountResponse" />
    <int:channel id="catRequestChannel" />
    <int:channel id="mataccountRequest" />
    <int:channel id="errorChannel"/>



    <int-http:inbound-gateway id="cwebAccountManagementGateway"     
        supported-methods="GET, POST" 
        request-channel="accountRequest"
        reply-channel="accountResponse" 
        mapped-request-headers="*"      
        mapped-response-headers="*" 
        view-name="/policies" 

        path="/services/{class}/{method}"
        reply-timeout="50000"
error-channel="errorChannel">




        <int-http:header name="serviceClass" expression="#pathVariables.class"/>
        <int-http:header name="serviceMethod" expression="#pathVariables.method"/>

    </int-http:inbound-gateway>


    <int:header-value-router input-channel="accountRequest"
        header-name="state"
        default-output-channel="accountRequest" resolution-required="false">
        <int:mapping value="MA"
            channel="mataccountRequest" />
            <int:mapping value="CA"
            channel="catRequestChannel" />

    </int:header-value-router>

    <int:service-activator id="accountServiceActivator" 
                input-channel="mataccountRequest"
                output-channel="accountResponse" 
                ref="serviceGatewayAdapter" 
                method="requestHandler" 
                send-timeout="60000"/>

        <int:service-activator id="caRequestActivator" 
                input-channel="catRequestChannel"
                output-channel="accountResponse" 
                ref="caServiceGatewayAdapter" 
                method="requestHandler" 
                send-timeout="60000"/>

                 <int:service-activator id="errorRequestActivator" 
                input-channel="errorChannel"
                output-channel="accountResponse" 
                ref="errorGatewayAdapter" 
                method="errorHandler" 
                send-timeout="60000"/>
```

for eg:This is my url

```
http://localhost:9085/springintegrationsample/create?mail=15999999@mail.com&idNumber=80010600010
```

if i edit the mail to some other values it ll get called twice
if i change agan it s working fine.I dont understand on what scenarios its getting called twice

Comment: I suggest you turn on DEBUG logging and follow the message(s) through the flow. Also take a look at your app server access log to see if the browser is sending two requests.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same "requestHandler" for both of your service activators, so its obvious it will be called twice.
You can't know which activator is called for the handler method as when you debug you can only check for the handler method being called. 
To better handle this, use different a handler method for each of your service activators. Even if they are using similar operations, it will be more clear and easy to debug.

I would suggest to add channel interceptors for logging of incoming and outgoing messages just to get a better idea.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and find out that I was using XML and Annotation both configurations.